# Помогите с ListFragment

Tags: android, java

Ничего не происходит...Выбивает приложение... Помогите разобраться

```
    import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.*;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.*;

public class MainListDreamweaver extends ListFragment{

    protected ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions op;

    //String[] imageUrls={"R.drawable.one","R.drawable.two","R.drawable.three"};
    String [] images={"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZrajzoEXNlRWjMGE9L3kqI1EsFN9P5HCNhMo4xaqLkWuhAixo",
        "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQH7hisM_szjOKlVdQvq6m_J4lETkWxQOlAk3SMWs051TFFnmWMCA",
        "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png"};
    public void onActivityCreated(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_listview_layout, container,false);

        op = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
//                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
            .build();

        setListAdapter(new ItemAdapter());

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //AnimateFirstDisplayListener.displayedImages.clear();
    }

//    private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
//        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
//        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
//        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
//        startActivity(intent);
//    }

    class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        //private ImageLoadingListener animate = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView text;
            public ImageView image;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText("Item " + (position + 1));

            loader.displayImage(images[position], holder.image, op, null);

            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Работаю с SliderMenu http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: стектрейс покажите. "Выбивает приложение..." - вы  же не предлагаете взять ваш снипет и создать вокруг него приложение?

Comment: вы при создание фрагмента возвращаете `null`

Answer (score 2):

Если используете ListFragment не нужно делать

```
list = (ListView) resultsLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

достаточно в layout'е дать листвью такой id: android:id="[@id](/users/11054/idd)/android:list"

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState  )
{
    View resultsLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_listview_layout,container, false);
    setListAdapter(new ItemAdapter());
    return resultsLayout;
}
```

Comment: Непомогло! Все ровно вылетает! переправил код, после чего перестало выбивать приложение, а просто показывает Progress кружок и пишет Загрузка.... (Код выше). почему? Что я опять не так сделал? Боюсь об стену головой....

Comment: @sviter-pro, не пытайтесь всунуть все сразу! Сначала сделайте обычный фрагмент, потом добавьте список с каким нибудь простеньким адаптером, добавьте свой адаптер, а потом уже все остальное!

Answer (score 0):

Ваш метод onCreateView возвращает null.

Исправьте вот так.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState  )
    {
        View resultsLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_listview_layout,container, false);

        list = (ListView) resultsLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ((ListView) list).setAdapter(new ItemAdapter());
        return resultsLayout;
    }
```

Comment: Все ровно ничего не происходит! Там просто идет:

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
     
    public HomeFragment(){}
     
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
          
        return rootView;
    }
}

и в R.layout.fragment_home стоит

Comment: <fragment android:name ="com.xxx.MainListCorelDraw"></fragment> (Код выше)

Comment: @sviter-pro еще вы делаете конструктор у адаптера пустым `new ItemAdapter()`

Comment: Немного переправил код, после чего перестало выбивать приложение, а просто показывает Progress кружок и пишет Загрузка.... (Код выше). почему? Что я опять не так сделал? Боюсь об стену головой....